# Returning Database values dependent on days not dates

Tags: sql, database, date, where-clause

Hi I'm trying to get a database to return some values, specifically, I need to return every invoice which is dated between the previous Monday to Sunday.

The reason for this is that this query will be ran on varying days, eg I need to return the results for the week Monday 5th August - Sunday 11th August at some point in the following week (12th - 18th).

I originally had this set up as a simple WHERE:

[WHERE TaxDate >= (GETDATE() - 7)]

because the invoices were done every monday so it worked itself out, but now they could be done any day of the following week. Are there any functions that I can use to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what arguments you will send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [datepart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28SQL.105%29.aspx) function with the day of week parameter:

```
WHERE Datepart(dw, TaxDate) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @currentdow int
declare @delta int
declare @startdate datetime
declare @endtime datetime
set @delta = 0 
set @startofweek = DatePart(dw, getDate())
while @scurrentdow <> 2
begin
  set @delta = @delta + 1
  set @currentdow = @currentdow - 1
  if @currentdow < 1
  begin
    set @currentdow = 7
  end   
end
set @startdate = DateSubtract(day,GetDate(), delta)
set @enddate = DateAdd(day, @startdate, 6)
```

long winded, but close I think.